# armv7 disassemble thumb instructions from raw binary snippet

Tags: disassembly, arm

I have a portion of a raw binary file that contains ARM instructions, specifically in Thumb mode (and I've manually disassembled a few instructions using the Architecture Manual, and they seemed reasonable).

I'm now trying to disassemble using objdump, but it always returns an ARM mode interpretation:

```
arm-none-eabi-objdump -marmv7 -Mno-force-thumb -b -D binFileSnippet.bin

    00000000 <.data>:
   0:   4b10b508        blmi    0x42d428
   4:   0711681a                        ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0x0711681a
   8:   2109d501        tstcs   r9, r1, lsl #10
   c:   06d26019                        ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0x06d26019
```

What's the best way to get thumb interpreted disassembled instructions?

Answer (score 1):

use capstone with your favorite binding
demo code use python (pip install capstone)

```
import binascii
from capstone import *
CODE = binascii.unhexlify("4b10b5080711681a2109d50106d26019")
md = Cs(CS_ARCH_ARM, CS_MODE_THUMB)
for i in md.disasm(CODE, 0x1000):
    print("0x%x" % i.address,end ="\t")
    print(binascii.hexlify(i.bytes),end = "\t")
    print("%s\t%s" %(i.mnemonic, i.op_str),end ="\n")
print("\n========thumb mode ends arm mode starts ==============\n")    
md = Cs(CS_ARCH_ARM, CS_MODE_ARM)
for i in md.disasm(CODE, 0x1000):
    print("0x%x" % i.address,end ="\t")
    print(binascii.hexlify(i.bytes),end = "\t")
    print("%s\t%s" %(i.mnemonic, i.op_str),end ="\n")
```

result

```
D:\>python disarmthumb.py
0x1000  b'4b10' asrs    r3, r1, #1
0x1002  b'b508' lsrs    r5, r6, #2
0x1004  b'0711' asrs    r7, r0, #4
0x1006  b'681a' subs    r0, r5, r1
0x1008  b'2109' lsrs    r1, r4, #4
0x100a  b'd501' lsls    r5, r2, #7
0x100c  b'06d2' bhs     #0x101c
0x100e  b'6019' adds    r0, r4, r5

========thumb mode ends arm mode starts ==============

0x1000  b'4b10b508'     ldmeq   r5!, {r0, r1, r3, r6, ip}
0x1004  b'0711681a'     bne     #0x1a05428
0x1008  b'2109d501'     bicseq  r0, r5, r1, lsr #18
0x100c  b'06d26019'     stmdbne r0!, {r1, r2, sb, ip, lr, pc}
```